# How 'set_password' method works?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, hash

I've been looking for this in DRF and Django doc but I can't find it.

Someone could explain how the base method works?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can see that directly in the source code. In fact, the method only [hash the given raw string and store it](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py#L97-L99) in the user :)

```py
    def set_password(self, raw_password):
        self.password = make_password(raw_password)
        self._password = raw_password
```